# React Apollo-Fetch: Using 'URI' instead of 'uri' causes an error. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

I'm currently working on an React-App with GraphQL as a backend.

Until this noon I used the following constant within my code:

```
const uri = 'https://...'
```

The only usage of the variable is:

```
const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch({ uri });
```

Because I like to follow the convention that constants shall have uppercase-names I changed the code to:

```
const URI = 'https://...
```

Suddenly my app stopped working. The error-message shown on the console:

```
Fetch API cannot load file:///graphql. URL scheme "file" is not supported.
```

After changing the constant-name back to lowercase everything works great again.

But I really would like to know: **What is the reason for the error?**

What has the constant-name to do with the URI-string? And why file-scheme?

Comment: Sounds silly but is it possible that you are missing out the change at `const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch({ URI });`

Comment: No, that wasn't the case. I changed all usages (two times) within my code to uppercase.